How to wire a relay 5v one side 24v other side?
I have a secondary ringer for a phone I use as a doorbell I have a black magic controller that uses 5v DC powering it. But I need to power a new doorbell camera and it needs the standard 24v power.
I believe that I could use a relay so it's 24v on the doorbell side and 5v on the ringer side but I have never understood how relays work or how to wire one.
Would that work? If so could someone break it down Barney style how to wire it?

This might be better on Electronic Engineering SE.

I'll post it over there thanks

Or Superuser. I think Black Magic is usually run off of a laptop.

I dono how you run a hardware like this off a computer this is what I have https://www.ebay.com/itm/122310636850

@keshlam You have this entirely wrong. Currently, the OP is running 5V DC through their doorbell button and powering their telephone-ringer directly, so that the telephone bell sounds when somebody presses the doorbell button. But now they want to replace their "dumb" doorbell button with one containing a camera (Ring, Nest, etc) which requires switching the doorbell circuit back to 24V AC. A relay with a 24V AC coil is absolutely the right thing to use here.

@nobody: As I said, I didn't understand the use case. I'll shut up and leave it to folks who are more certain

Yes, a relay is the right thing to use here. You need a relay that accepts
24V AC on its coil (the same type of power that standard video doorbells require) and has set of "normally open" contacts (either a "single pole / single throw" relay that's normally open, or use the common and normally open terminal of a "single pole / double throw" relay). You then wire up your 5V DC supply and telephone ring-generator to the contact side, just like you have them currently wired up to the doorbell button.
I suggest looking for a relay that accepts 10V - 30V AC on its coil, since doorbell transformers can vary quite a bit in the actual voltage they deliver.
One example that a quick web search turned up is the Functional Devices RIBU1C-N4.
+---[24 VAC XFMR]----[Video Doorbell]---------+
|                                             |           
|                                             |
+------------------------------------[coil ]--+
                                     [Relay]
                   +--[5V DC]--------[ NO  ]--+
                   |                          |
                   |                          |
                   +------[ring generator]----+


@DIY75 You're not fooling anyone with the constant name changes Ruskes.

Nice ASCII diagram, nobody! +1.
